# Citing an arXiv pre-print in a `bib` file

Tags: biblatex

I need to cite an arXiv pre-print, as a reference in Overleaf. Its current BibTeX citation is:

```
@misc{https://doi.org/10.48550/arxiv.1107.1153,
  doi = {10.48550/ARXIV.1107.1153},
  
  url = {https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.1153},
  
  author = {Li, J. L. Xiang and Szegedy, Balazs},
  
  keywords = {Combinatorics (math.CO), FOS: Mathematics, FOS: Mathematics},
  
  title = {On the logarithimic calculus and Sidorenko's conjecture},
  
  publisher = {arXiv},
  
  year = {2011},
  
  copyright = {arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license}
}
```

After compilation, however, it is rendered as below:

[image: The compiled version of above citation.]

I do not see the arXiv paper number, which I believe is `arxiv.1107.1153`. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Your .bib entry does not provide a field that holds the arXiv paper number, so I would rather expect it not to be printed. Anyways, without knowing which packages and macros you use to typeset your bibliography and citations, it is hard to help you.

Comment: The output you get crucially depends on the bibliography style you are using. Many modern bibliography styles will show the URL or DOI, but apparently you are using a style that does not. If you want more specific help, please tell us which style you use and more about your general bibliography and citation setup. This is best done in a compilable and short example document (what people often call an MWE) that contains the relevant code and as little else as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to include that information within the `pages` field. Adding `1107.1153` should prove sufficient. (I would exclude the `arxiv` prefix, as it already ought appear in the journal name. I would add that via `howpuiblished`, should you elect to maintain this citation as a `@misc` entity.)

Since you tagged this as BibLaTeX, I will presume that you are actually using that more [modern approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25702/134641), including biber.

In that case, it would be better to cite it as follows:

```
@article{li:logarithimic,
  doi = {10.48550/ARXIV.1107.1153},
  author = {Li, J. L. Xiang and Szegedy, Balazs},
  title = {On the logarithimic calculus and Sidorenko's conjecture},
  journal = {arXiv},
  publisher = {Cornell University},
  year = {2011},
  eprint       = {math.CO/1107.1153},
  pages = {1107.1153},
  pubstate      = {\bibstring{prepublished}},
}
```

Some prefer to use `@online`, however I think pre-prints ought be cited as articles. Note also that I would not consider *arXiv* to be the publisher. Given that the pre-print has only a single version, I suggest you only provide the `doi` and not the `url` field. You can then use [one of](https://newbedev.com/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-dois-url-or-isbn) many approaches to ensure it automatically links correctly. I would also suggest you link to `doi.org` and not `dx.doi.org`, as that is [no longer recommended](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/dois-urls).